# Inserting a new column with values, from another dataframe, based on another column value in R

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes.

For **df1**, they are transaction records:

```
date | description   | amount
=============================
xxxx | insurance-abc | 100
xxxx | grocery-xyz   | 50
xxxx | insurance-jkl | 150
xxxx | misc-spend    | 50
xxxx | grocery-abc   | 70
```

For **df2**, it contains category information

```
description | category
======================
insurance   | INS
grocery     | GRY
```

The end state, I am looking to have this inside **df3**

```
date | description   | amount | category
========================================
xxxx | insurance-abc | 100    | INS
xxxx | grocery-xyz   | 50     | GRY
xxxx | insurance-jkl | 150    | INS
xxxx | misc-spend    | 50     |
xxxx | grocery-abc   | 70     | GRY
```

I attempted to use mutate() and ifelse() and grepl() for partial string match, but I think this is  not the way to go. Because as I find certain keywords, I will add them into df2 and have newer categories.

Is there to do a partial string search on existing column and where there is a match, create the new category and insert value from another datatable, like the example I cited above?

Thanks!

df1 and df2 for copy/paste:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~date, ~description, ~amount,
  "xxxx", "insurance-abc",100,
  "xxxx", "grocery-xyz",  50,
  "xxxx", "insurance-jkl",150,
  "xxxx", "misc-spend", 50,
  "xxxx", "grocery-abc",  70
  )

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~description, ~category,
  "insurance", "INS",
  "grocery",   "GRY"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::separate()` you can split `description` into two columns, split by the “-”. Then you left join (`dplyr::left_join()`) df1 and df2 by `description`. `tidyr::unite()` can be used to reverse the separation from the first step.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 |> 
  separate(description, into = c("description", "desc_b")) |> 
  left_join(df2) |> 
  unite("description", description, desc_b, sep = "-")
#> Joining, by = "description"
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   date  description   amount category
#>   <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 xxxx  insurance-abc    100 INS     
#> 2 xxxx  grocery-xyz       50 GRY     
#> 3 xxxx  insurance-jkl    150 INS     
#> 4 xxxx  grocery-abc       70 GRY     
#> 5 xxxx  misc-spend        50 <NA>
```

Alternatively you can set `remove` in `separate()` to `FALSE`, that way you don’t have to use `unite()` and can just drop the additional columns.

```r
    df1 |> 
      separate(description, into = c("desc_a", "desc_b"), remove = FALSE) |> 
      left_join(df2, by = c("desc_a" = "description")) |> 
      select(-starts_with("desc_"))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#>   date  description   amount category
#>   <chr> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>   
#> 1 xxxx  insurance-abc    100 INS     
#> 2 xxxx  grocery-xyz       50 GRY     
#> 3 xxxx  insurance-jkl    150 INS     
#> 4 xxxx  grocery-abc       70 GRY     
#> 5 xxxx  misc-spend        50 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I was thinking if I can take the values from df2 and then have them inserted into df1 instead. Insurance and groceries are just broad example. And there may be some description which is not present in df2. In short, I'm looking to look at every row in df1, check the description if it matches any description from df2. If there are, then add the 'category' value into df1

Comment: That is what this code is doing. A left join means that all rows in df1 will be kept and combined with rows from df2 if there is a match in `description`. If a row in df1 does not have a match in df2 it will still be kept. I updated my answer to make that more explicit.